# SQL Server bcp tool on AWS GLUE job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-glue-spark

any one has tried sql server bcp utility on aws Glue job (Python shell or Spark type)?

bcp tool needs to be installed using Sudo yum commands however those are not supported on Glue.

```
sudo yum install mssql-tools unixODBC-devel
```

reference link from Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver16

Is there any solution or an alternative that I can approach ?

Comment: Have you tried connecting directly to SQL Server from AWS Glue via JDBC and copy data to destination ?

Comment: how? you mean get data exported to s3? I want table to table bulk copy.